# Display collections data in powerapps listbox

Tags: powerapps

I have created a collections with array data. I am not able to fetch all data at once and not able to show in listbox. Please provide me suggestion. Please find the screenshot
[image]

Comment: How are you trying to fetch the data, and what do you mean by "not able to show in listbox" - do you get an error?

Comment: I am not able to fetch even. I am trying with this code in function: simpleCollection.LineItems